# Firebase AuthUI not calling onActivityResult

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm building an Android app that uses Firebase AuthUI to handle user login.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.3'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:6.2.0'
```

When my activity starts and checks if the user is signed in... and if not it calls startActivityForResult. See code below.

When AuthUI completes it never calls onActivityResult. Instead the startup activity's onRestart() is called.

Any suggestions as to how I can get onActivityResult called?

```
   private fun startFirebaseAuthActivity() {
        Timber.d("startFirebaseAuthActivity(): ")
        EventBus.getDefault().post(MyEvents.Companion.StopListFragment())
        // Choose authentication providers
        val providers = arrayListOf(
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
        )

        // Create and launch sign-in intent
        startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN
        )
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        Timber.d("onActivityResult(): ")

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            val response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data)

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && response != null) {
                // Successfully signed in
                auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                newUser = User(auth!!.currentUser!!)
                isNewUser = response.isNewUser
                Timber.d("onActivityResult(): isNewUser=$isNewUser")
                if (isNewUser) {
                    createNewUser()
                } 

            } else {
                // Sign in failed.
                // If response is null the user canceled the sign-in flow using the back button.
                // Otherwise check response.getError().getErrorCode() and handle the error.

                when {
                    response == null -> {
                        //If no response from the Server
                        Timber.d("onActivityResult(): sign_in_cancelled.")
                        showSnackbar(R.string.sign_in_cancelled)
                    }

                    response.error?.errorCode == ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK -> {
                        //If there was a network problem the user's phone
                        Timber.d("onActivityResult(): no_internet_connection")
                        showSnackbar(R.string.no_internet_connection)
                    }

                    response.error?.errorCode == ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN_ERROR -> {
                        //If the error cause was unknown
                        Timber.e("onActivityResult(): unknown_error")
                        showSnackbar(R.string.unknown_error)

                    }
                    else -> {

                        Timber.e("onActivityResult(): unknown_sign_in_response")
                        showSnackbar(R.string.unknown_sign_in_response) //if the sign in response was unknown
                    }
                }
                startFirebaseAuthActivity()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i didn't get it can you tell me why you called `startFirebaseAuthActivity()` from the `onActivityResult()`

Comment: I do not call startFirebaseAuthActivity() from onActivityResult(). In my startup Activity's onStart() method (not shown) I check if the user is signed in to Firebase. If not, startFirebaseAuthActivity() is called which in turn calls AuthUI via startActivityForResult. My expectation is that when AuthUI finishes, my startup Activity resumes via onActivityResult... but it does not... it resumes via onRestart().

Comment: did you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue with code similar to the following

```
    if (token?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
        val activityIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(activityIntent)
    } else {
        val loginIntent = AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
            .build()
        startActivityForResult(loginIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
    }
    finish()
```

The issue was the finish outside of the if else block.   This was finishing my activity before the result could be returned from the AuthUI activity.   Moving the finish up to the token case solved the problem for me

```
    if (token?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
        val activityIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(activityIntent)
        finish()
    } else {
        val loginIntent = AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
            .build()
        startActivityForResult(loginIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
    }
```

I didn't see a finish() in your code, but maybe something similar is completing the activity before the result can be returned.